# concatenate all the text files in all the sub folders into one giant text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, cat, merge

Ok so the situation is that I have an unknown number of sub-directories that all follow the same naming profile

folder0, folder1, folder2, folder3 etc

Now each folder will have 3 text files and these text files will have the same 3 file names in all folders

file1 file2 file3

I would like to find an easy way to concatenate all the text files in all the folders into one text file, starting in folder0 with file1, then file2, then file3 and the same order in all folders.

Now for a small number of folders I could use cat

```
cat folder0/file1 folder0/file2 folder0/file3 folder1/file1 folder1/file2 folder1/file3 folder2/file1 folder2/file2 folder2/file3 folder3/file1 folder3/file2 folder3/file3 > textfile
```

but the number of folders is unknown and could range into the 100's or 1000's

anybody have any indea of a script that would acomplish this.

Comment: Check the `find` command.

Comment: Are the file names really in sequential, numerical order? Like `file1`, `file2`, `file3` etc? Or can they be named things like `foobar`, `whatever`, `haha`, and you need to specify the order you want them in?

Comment: the names are really file1 file2 file3, and they need to be in a set order

Answer (score 2):

With only unix tools and pipes:

```
find ./ -type f -regex './folder[0-9]+/file[0-9]+' -print0 | sort -zV | xargs --null cat
```

**Explanation:**

`find` searches for all files matching some condition

1. `./` tells `find` to search from where you are currently at, i.e. your working directory
2. `-type f` tells `find` to only find files, in case there ever is a directory named as a file
3. `-regex` tells `find` to only search for files where the whole path of the file matches the given pattern. In this case "./folder" followed by one or more digits, followed by a new directory and then "file" followed by one or more digits.
4. `-print0` tells `find` to output the files it found separated by a null character, which is guaranteed to not appear in file names and will work even if your file names contain newlines, which they could

`sort` sorts the list it gets

1. the `-z` tells `sort` to sort null character separated entries instead of newline separated ones, as would be the default
2. the `-V` tells `sort` to sort the entries as a human would intuitively sort them, i.e. `file11` comes after both `file1` and `file2`, not in the middle.

`xargs` just uses the entries it gets and passes them as argument to `cat`. `--null` tells `xargs`, you guessed it, to tell apart different entries by a null character between them, not blanks or newlines.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -r -- folder<->/file<1-3>(nN) -- cat > hugefile
```

With `bash`, and with GNU tools:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
print0() { (( $# == 0 )) || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
 
xargs -r0a <(
  print0 folder+([0123456789])/file[123] | sort -zV
  ) cat > hugefile
```

Where `+([0123456789])` (with `extglob` which enables some of ksh's advanced glob operators, including `+(...)`) is the equivalent of zsh's `<->` (any sequence of ASCII decimal digits), GNU `sort -V` does the equivalent of zsh's `n` glob qualifier (for numeric sorting so that `folder10` comes after `folder9` and not between `folder1` and `folder2` with the default alphabetical sorting), `nullglob` for the `N` glob qualifier and GNU `xargs` is used in place of zsh's `zargs` to split the list to avoid *arg list too long* errors.

We define a `print0` function that prints its arguments NUL-delimited (as bash doesn't have `zsh`'s `print -rNC1`), though here, given that file paths won't contain any of the characters that are special to `xargs` without `-0`, we might as well print them newline  separated with `printf '%s\n'` and ignore that fact that it would print an empty line if the list was empty given that `xargs` will ignore that line anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Up to a certain number of folders, you can do:

```
cat folder*/* > file
```

Or, to target specific files/directories only:

```
cat {folder1,folder2,folder3}/{file1,file2,file3} > file
```

If the names really do consist of a fixed string and sequential numbers, you can further simplify to

```
cat folder{1..3}/file{1..3} > file
```

Now, this will fail if you have a huge number of files and folders, but it should work for most cases. For instance, on my machine, I created 3000 files in 1000 directories with:

```
mkdir folder{1..1000}
touch folder{1..1000}/file{1..3}
for f in */*; do echo "$f" > $f; done
```

And then concatenated all files into one with:

```
cat folder*/* > file
```

Which gives a file with 3000 lines.

If, however, you run into issues with this, you can always use `find`:

```
find folder1 folder2 folder3 -name "file[123]" -exec cat {} + > file
```

Or

```
find folder* -name "file[123]" -exec cat {} + > file
```

***CAVEAT***: none of these approaches will let you specify the order, but they should have the same order in all directories.

Comment: Adding `-type f` in `find` may help to be on the safe side :)